# Why am I getting a Syntax Error in Python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm a beginner of Python and I got a problem here. I just copied what my textbook says but I got an error here.  I put the following code.

```
if return_age != 0:
    print"Your age is %s years" %(return_age)
```

Then my laptop says

```
File "<ipython-input-3-8c2f6bc68809>", line 15
 print"Your age is %s years" %(return_age)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please explain how to correct this bug.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Answer (score 3):

```
# works in python 2
return_age = 4
if return_age != 0:
    print "Your age is %s years" %(return_age)

# works in python 3 
return_age = 4
if return_age != 0:
    print("Your age is %s years" %(return_age))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Thanks, I copied what you wrote and it worked!

Comment: @MakotoNakai Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Print is a function in Python 3, so you need parentheses.

Comment: Thanks, I added parentheses and now my error is corrected!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3.x
Try this

```
print("Your age is %s years" %(return_age))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 print"Your age is %s years" %(return_age)
```

You are using `Python 3.x` version and using a `Python 2.x` code.

If you want to use `Python 2.x` then this code will work.

Or else use the following code:

```
print("Your age is %s years" %(return_age))
```